# Google Analytics : Hit count limit is per account or per tracking ID

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, web-traffic

I have a Google Analytics 360 account with limit of 500 million per month. I have created two tracking ids(Properties). My question is 500M limit is per tracking id or for account (all tracking ids)?

Comment: I'd bet account, but you should check your contract with Google or consult your Google account manager.

Comment: @kgrg I checked with the Google Manager and it is for Account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit is for all tracking accounts. The hits are registered for your organization. You can see the total usage under billing->usage.